# Tests for positively skewed data with large enough samples?

Tags: r, t-test, nonparametric, sample-size, skewness

I'm new to statistic tests so I need a little bit of help with them. Most of my data has distribution similar to the histogram below.

[image]

As it can be seen from the histogram, the data is positively skewed (for example, calculated skewness for this particular variable lol$Total_per_100_k is 1.286938). Most of my sample sizes are somewhere between 80 and 170. I do not know the distribution of any of my variables. Which tests can I use on this data?

For example, which tests can I use to test if the mean of the sample is greater than some value? I'm not sure if I can use one sample t-test because my data doesn't have normal distribution. But my samples are bigger than n=50, so maybe I can use t-test?

When I log-transform the data, the transformed data has normal distribution. But how well can those results (results from tests done on transformed data) be applied to the original data?

Comment: 0.  Welcome to CV.SE. 1. Off the bat, if you are worried about normality you might want to consider a non-parametric test (e.g. as Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney). 2. We have some excellent threads on this already, (e.g. [Should I use t-test on highly skewed and discrete data?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/111320/), [Should I use t-test on highly skewed data ? Scientific proof, please?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/110801)) so I would suggest viewing them. 3. The skew does not seem horribly pathological so I suspect that the sample mean converges in distribution to a Gaussian.

Comment: That histogram might look like a gamma distribution ... if you want more help than a few links, you need to tell us your research hypothesis  and other context ...