# Doing a t-test on a normally distributed difference of two non normal distributions

Tags: python, t-test, methodology, ab-test, two-sample

I have two populations of donations (segment 2 people were subject to a different form):

```
              seg 1        seg 2
count   1772.000000  1645.000000
mean      93.576185   108.259574
std      301.248967   241.837942
min        3.000000     3.000000
25%       20.000000    20.000000
50%       40.000000    50.000000
75%       72.750000   100.000000
max     9000.000000  6200.000000
```

They don't look very normal. This is the log distribution:

[image]

But their difference does:

```
means = []
for i in range(0,10000):
  means.append(df_segment_1.sample(1772, replace=True).mean() - df_segment_2.sample(1645, replace=True).mean())

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline

np.random.seed(42)

plt.hist(means, density=True, bins=30)  # density=False would make counts
plt.ylabel('Probability')
plt.xlabel('Mean difference of donations');
```

[image]

So I wanted to know how can I do a t-test on this population in order to know if segment 2 is significantly higher than segment 1?

Comment: Do you have some kind of pairing of your observations?

Comment: What do you mean by pairing in my informations, @Dave ?

Comment: Do you have a natural way of pairing your observations, such as a subject before and after a treatment? I do not follow what `means.append(df_segment_1.sample(170).mean() - df_segment_2.sample(160).mean())` means. // You say you have two populations. "Pop

Comment: I'm not sure @Dave ... I have two populations of donators (segment 2 are people who were subject to a different form)

Comment: What does the `means.append(df_segment_1.sample(170).mean() - df_segment_2.sample(160).mean())` line do? // Ignore the "population" fragment. That is a technicality not worth discussing at this time. (I'll explain later.)

Comment: It compares the mean of two randomly chosen samples of 10% of each segment, @Dave .

Comment: What you're doing with that as akin to something called bootstrap. Try sampling with the original sample sizes but with replacement.

Comment: What do you mean by the original sample size @Dave ? Like the original segment size (1772 and 1645)? I tried that and it returns only one value. How do I do replacement? What does that mean?

Comment: Yes, use the original segment sizes. // "With replacement" means that a sample of $(1,2,3,4,5)$ could be sampled as $(3,2,3,4,1)$.

Comment: Ok, I did it and updated the question with the distribution of the differences, @Dave , thanks. How can do a t-test to be sure the difference is significant from there?

Comment: You don't do a t-test on that. You do that to show that the sampling distribution of the difference in means is approximately normal, which is what the t-test requires. Now you can go do the t-test on your original data (though it does not appear that you will get a small p-value).

Comment: Many thanks, @Dave , I understand now. do you have any references I could cite? In any case, should I rather use a non-parametric test like the U-test?

Comment: There is much debate about what test to use for something like this. Frank Harrell argues to go for the Wilcoxon Mann-Whitney U test by default. I am tempted to do that, though I have found that the t-test can be quite robust in large sample sizes and that colleagues and customers are more comfortable using the familiar t-test. However you proceed, you do not go run the Wilcoxon test just because you didn't like the result of the t-test. // Efron invented/discovered bootstrap, but it is routine to appeal to the central limit theorem when you have many observations like you do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resampling *with* replacement done is very appropriate and shows  that the distribution of mean differences is close to Gaussian. This suggest that using a $t$-test is *not* completely misguided. We can use a $t$-test here but it is probably not our best option. On that regard, if want to use a $t$-test it will be  safer to use [Welch $t$-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t-test) instead of Student's $t$-test to avoid assuming equal variances.

Please note that the fact that your raw data is non-normal does not invalidate the test - as mentioned in Dave's comment we care for the difference between the two means, not the samples themselves. This has been extensively covered a couple times here. e.g. see:

- *[T-test for non normal when N>50?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9573/t-test-for-non-normal-when-n50?rq=1)*
- *[Should I use t-test on highly skewed data ? Scientific proof, please?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/110801/should-i-use-t-test-on-highly-skewed-data-scientific-proof-please)*

That said, using [Mann-Whitney-Wilcoxon rank-sum test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test), is a potentially better approach because it as almost as powerful (i.e. it will detect an effect if it is there) as the $t$-test if the normality assumption holds and more powerful if it does not. Somewhat simplistically, we will test of our two samples are sampled from continuous distributions with equal medians.

I would suggest reading Glen_b's exceptional answer in the thread: *[How to choose between t-test or non-parametric test e.g. Wilcoxon in small samples](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/121852/how-to-choose-between-t-test-or-non-parametric-test-e-g-wilcoxon-in-small-sampl?rq=1)* if you want some quick formal references. For a book: *[Nonparametric Statistical Methods](https://www.wiley.com/en-gb/Nonparametric+Statistical+Methods%2C+3rd+Edition-p-9780470387375)* by Hollander et al. is consider quite standard. If not too averse towards R, *[Nonparametric Statistical Methods Using R](https://www.routledge.com/Nonparametric-Statistical-Methods-Using-R/Kloke-McKean/p/book/9780367739720)* by Kloke & McKean is also very good (the R code is easy to follow, nothing crazy), I found the pace and the exposition was really nice.